# Rolagem horizontal no iPhone5

Tags: javascript, css, resolução-de-tela

O site abre perfeitamente em todos os aparelhos, menos no iPhone 4 e 5.
Nesses eles ficam com rolagem horizontal, como se fosse maior que a resolução.

http://homologacao.programamaistop.com.br/

Assim, quando abre, o modal não fica centralizado!

Esse problema é comum em iPhone 5 ?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Essa imagem que você postou está assim porquê você arrastou ? Em todo caso, adicione um `overflow-x: hidden` quando a resolução for menor que `480px;`. Mas não deveria estar assim. Tem algum elemento que está usando `width` com tamanho fixo ao invés de `100%`. É melhor resolver isso do que colocar um `overflow`. Pode ser que seja o modal. Você vai ter que usar no CSS o `width: 100% !important` para que funcione.

Comment: O problema é que só não funciona no iPhone 4 e 5! testei em aparelho android com resolução pequena e fica tudo certo!

Comment: Eu olhei seu código fonte e percebi que tem uma tag assim: 
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`. Troque por essa e veja se funciona:
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">`.

Comment: Obrigada, vou tentar.
Mas me explica como funciona? rs

Comment: Esse site https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag e esse site http://tableless.com.br/manipulando-metatag-viewport/ pode te ajudar a entender essa meta tag. Basicamente ela serve para controlar o layout da página em aparelhos móveis. O `viewport` é a área que seu site vai ocupar na tela. As vezes quando algum elemento da tela explode, está grande demais em um determinado aparelho é por falta desta tag configurada para funcionar no dispositivo.